# unexpected behaviour when trying to float buttons to the right hand side

Tags: css, html

I am trying to move the buttons above the chart in my [My fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/463105/) to the right hand side.

In my div with the id *range-butts-index* shown below I tried using the class *pefBut* however when I do this the buttons disappear. When I remove the class the buttons come back however on the left handside. I don't understand why this class makes the buttons disappear?

**html**

```
<div id="IndexArea">
        <div id="range-butts-index" class='perfBut'>
            <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all" data-range="5">5d</button>
            <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all" data-range="20">MTD</button>
            <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all" data-range="999">Max</button>
        </div>
        <div id="chartIndexPerf"/div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.perfBut {
 float: right;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure why it disappears.You should use flex instead of floats.

Wrap div around your current div, make it display flex and set justify-content to flex-end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this instead of `float: right`:

```
.perfBut {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  justify-content: right;
}
```

You can see the result here:
https://jsbin.com/yugoliduya/edit?css,output